# How to return the null values and value within the same column by using textbox search function

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just a quick question. I have tried so many possibilities to get the null value and value within the date column like using ISNULL, NULL, 0, but returning 0 result. I have no idea how to program to get the null value from the creation date.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        FillDates();
    }
}

private void FillDates()
{
    txtDateS.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("01-01-yyyy");
    txtDateE.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("12-31-yyyy");
}

private string ConvertDate(Object obj)
{
    if (obj is DateTime)
    {
         return ((DateTime)obj).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
    else
    {
        return obj.ToString();
    }
}

protected void AddRowItem(StringBuilder sb, SqlDataReader reader, int index)
{
    sb.Append("<tr><td>").Append(index).Append("</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>").Append(ConvertDate(reader[0])).Append("</td>");

    sb.Append("</tr>");
}   

protected int DoItemList(SqlConnection connection, StringBuilder sb, string DateS, string DateE, string filter)
{
    string sql = "";
    SqlCommand readCommand = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    int count = 0;

    try
    {
        string itemFilter = DoFilter(filter);

        sql = "SELECT v.[Code] FROM [CAS].[dbo].[Van] v WHERE v.[Created_DateTime]>='" + DateStart + "' and b.[Created_DateTime]<='" + DateEnd + "';

        readCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count++;
            AddRowItem(sb, reader, count);
        }

        reader.Close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //
    }
    return count;
}
```

The website I to key in the textbox

```
<div>
      <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Width="100px">Date From:</asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox id="txtDateS" runat="server" Width="184px"></asp:TextBox><br />
      <br/>
      <asp:Label id="Label2" runat="server" Width="100px">Creation date from:</asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox id="txtDateE" runat="server" Width="184px"></asp:TextBox><br />
  
      <asp:Button id="cmdRun" runat="server" Width="91px" Height="24px" Text="Run" onclick="cmdRun_Click"></asp:Button>
      <asp:Label id="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      <hr noshade>
</div>
```

Result output

| Code | Creation date |
| --- | --- |
| A0001 | 2018-08-12 |
| A0002 | null |

To further clarify, the Created_DateTime can have null values. So when I filter by the Created_DateTime using the textboxes, it only shows the values where Created_DateTime is not null. E.g. for the start date, I key in 2021-01-30, and end date I key in 2021-12-30. It only shows the rows with a Created_DateTime, but not when there is a null value Created_DateTime.

Comment: You might consider providing us with enough information to understand what you mean... where is this null value? What is your desired behaviour? Is it in SQL or C# that you need a solution?

Comment: FYI, you **should** be using `SqlParameter`s to pass your dates to your query, as it is you are wide open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Trying to guess what you might be asking, I think we need to see the code for `AddRowItem`.

Comment: Three-part names are a bad habit. Imagine you change your connection string to use a different database. But all your queries will still be accessing the CAS database! This leads to madness.

Comment: Thank you guys. I cannot paste over the code here because too long. By the ways, the data I want is to show the null creation date and creation date at the same time. E.g. I key in the start date and end end date into the textbox and show the creation date data, but unfortunately, it didn't show the null value row from server sql. The result I want is to show the data with null creation date and data will value creation date. Hope it may clarify you question

Comment: We don't want to see all your code, we want a [MRE] i.e. you create the smallest amount of code necessary to demonstrate the issue. Frequently this will allow you to solve it yourself, but if not it will allow us to understand it.

Comment: "but unfortunately, it didn't show the null value row from server sql." But what does this mean? You need to step through the debugger, check the actual SQL query you are running (and add it to your question), run it in SSMS to see that its returning the correct results, then check what comes back in your datareader. Given you haven't shown us the code for `AddRowItem` you might just not be handling null values in the reader correctly.

Comment: And your query `SELECT v.[Code] FROM [CAS].[dbo].[Van]` doesn't return the `v.[Created_Date]` column.

Comment: @DaleK, let me write the code based on minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @DaleK, I have edited the code. I hope it may help you clarify the question

Comment: So what do you actually get displayed? As as I noted above, your query doesn't pull the created date, so how are you getting it? If you put a breakpoint in `ConvertDate` you should see what is happening (cos thats where the issue lies).

Comment: @DaleK, from my database, the Created_DateTime have null value, when I filtering by the creation date on the textbox, it only show the value with creation date, but not for the null creation date. E.g. the start date, I key in 2021-01-30, and end date I key in 2021-12-30. It only show the value with creation date, but the null value creation date didn't output

Comment: Please add that information to your question, because that is what we need to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems you *always* want to return records with a `NULL` `Created_DateTime`. In which case this is how you do it.

```
SELECT v.Code
FROM dbo.Van v
WHERE (
    v.Created_DateTime >= @DateStart
    -- When dealing with dates that are stored as datetime and could therefore have an accidental time component
    -- its safer to use less than a day in the future
    AND v.Created_DateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE,@DateEnd))
)
OR v.Created_DateTime IS NULL;
```

Note I am showing you the query you *should* be using which uses parameters rather than string concatenation. Because string concatenation leaves you open to SQL Injection.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you very much. I just missing the "OR IS NULL" on the WHERE query. Thank you. You save my day

Comment: I will change to SQL injection. Thank you for you advise and suggestion. Have a good day